# Generic and overridable controller method with optional generic parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following generic controller:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase<TEntity, TEntityDto>
{
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TEntityDto>>> GetAll()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to be able to filter entities based on query parameters on the same route as the generic controller (that returns *all* entities). Therefor my idea was to override the generic controller and rewriting it to:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase<TEntity, TEntityDto, TQueryParams>
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TEntityDto>>> GetAll(TQueryParams? queryParams)
    {
        // Notice the service layer method is called without parameters in the generic controller
        var instances = await _service.GetAll();

        return Ok(instances);
    }
}
```

```
public class DogsController : EntityControllerBase<Dog,DogDto>
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DogDto>>> GetAll(DogQueryParams queryParams)
        {
            var instances = await _service.ListDogs(queryParams.kennel, queryParams.birthYear);
            return Ok(instances);
        }
}
```

However, I get the error: `Only non-nullable value type could be underlying of 'System.Nullable'`.

**Am I using the right approach?**

What is the correct way to achieve the desired behavior? (which is to be able to override the base controller method `GetAll` when I need to filter output based on optional query parameters).

Comment: You can only mark as nullable, that wich is not already nullable. Implicitly, all refrence types are nullable by nature. And this one is not limited to accepting only structs or the like | Even in C# 8.0, Non-nullable reference types are not turned on by default. They still need a switch. And even with that, they are too different in MSIL to be used for a generic.

Comment: Don't try to write generic code. This is not best for business purpose because everything is changeable. Change your mindset. Let's try to use CQRS. And watch this [Jimmy Bogard - SOLID Architecture in Slices not Layers](https://youtu.be/wTd-VcJCs_M)

Comment: @kogoia So you're recommending that I not use the generic controller and just write `GetAll` controllers for every domain model? I would appreciate some guidance since I haven't used C# in a large project before (come from golang/python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error tells you that you "can only mark nullable, that which is not already nullable."

Reference types are inherently nullable. Indeed only with C# 8.0 we receive support for *non-nullable* reference types. With a compiler switch, as using it as default would be problematic.

structs in turn are inherently non-nullable. The nullable syntax was originally invented for them. With C# 8.0 it will get it's first expansion, afaik.

As you did not limit `TQueryParams` via a where clause, the compiler can only assume things that apply to both structs **and** classes. For generics, it always uses the "smallest common denominator".

But note that even with the C# 8.0 support for non-nullable reference types, to my knowledge the MSIL implementation is so different you can not use them interchangeably. You still have to decide for class or struct, to use nullable Syntax.

Comment: So you are saying that it ought to work already if I remove the `?`/`Nullable<>`?

Comment: Is my problem not a common ocurrence? Am I using the right approach?

Comment: @elliott: Either remove teh question mark from `TQueryParams? queryParams`. Or limit `where TQueryParams : struct`. Both of wich can have unwanted effects. | I can not really tell you if this is a common thing, as I do not know that much about MVC.